# Telerik Upload Control in DNN just posts back without uploading

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

Ultimately, what I would like to do is upload files directly into the database, so I updated this question with the code I'm using to write to the database.

I am developing a module in DotNetNuke using Telerik controls. I need to upload files to the server in the user interface, so I am using the RadUpload control and the RadProgressArea/RadProgressManager.

Here is my ASP:

```
<telerik:RadUpload ID="RadUpload1" runat="server" ControlObjectsVisibility="CheckBoxes, RemoveButtons, ClearButtons"
                AllowedFileExtensions=".doc,.docx,.pdf,.tiff,.gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.xls,.xlsx" MaxFileInputsCount="2"
                MaxFileSize="10000000" InitialFileInputsCount="2">
            </telerik:RadUpload>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload File(s)" />
            <telerik:RadProgressArea ID="RadProgressArea1" runat="server" ProgressIndicators="TotalProgressBar, TotalProgress, RequestSize, FilesCountBar, FilesCount, SelectedFilesCount, CurrentFileName, TimeElapsed, TimeEstimated, TransferSpeed">
            </telerik:RadProgressArea>
            <br />
            <telerik:RadProgressManager ID="RadProgressManager1" Runat="server" />
```

And here is my VB:

```
   Protected Sub UploadButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UploadButton.Click
    If RadUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count > 0 Then
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
    End If
    For Each file As UploadedFile In RadUpload1.UploadedFiles
        Dim bytes(file.ContentLength - 1) As Byte
        file.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, file.ContentLength)
        Try
            ' Create the sales order in the database on page load so that the salesorderid is unique
            Dim connection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SiteSqlServer").ConnectionString
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(connection)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TTC_UploadedFiles ([Name], [Size], [Content]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", file.GetName())
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", bytes.Length)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", bytes)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Label1.Text = ex.ToString
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

When I hit the button, it does a postback to the page, but the files do not get uploaded. I tried using the autoupload functions and specifying pysical and virtual paths but that didn't work. I did it exactly like they said. I manually registered the controls in my web.config, then removed them and used the auto-register feature to re-register thinking maybe I did something wrong, but I'm still at a loss.

Here's where I spent the last couple hours:
[Upload Overview][3]
[Files are not uploaded][4]

Can someone help me get this upload control and progress indicator working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not direct related to your question. I use AsyncUpload, which can select muliple files at once, and upload files to database. The following is the sample code. I strip out the validation codes for the sake of simplicity.

```
<!-- ASPX page -->
<telerik:RadProgressManager runat="server" ID="RadProgressManager1" />
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="AsyncUpload1" InputSize="40" MaxFileSize="10485760">
</telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
<telerik:RadProgressArea runat="server" ID="RadProgressArea1">
</telerik:RadProgressArea>

// Code behind
ImageManager.InsertImage(AsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles);

// In business logic
public static void InsertImage(UploadedFileCollection uploadedFileCollection)
{   
   foreach (UploadedFile uploadedFile in uploadedFileCollection)
   {  
      string filename = uploadedFile.GetName();   

      // Process the image into byte array
      Stream imgStream = uploadedFile.InputStream;
      int imgLen = uploadedFile.ContentLength;
      byte[] imgBinaryData = new byte[imgLen]; 
      imgStream.Read(imgBinaryData, 0, imgLen);

      // Get width and height
      Image originalimg = Image.FromStream(imgStream);

      // Get rid of white spaces
      filename = string.Concat(Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename),
         "[^\\w-]", string.Empty), Path.GetExtension(filename));

      // Now you get - 
      // imgLen
      // filename
      // imgBinaryData
      // originalimg.Height;
      // originalimg.Width;
   }  
}
```

**Edit**: In web.config, depending on what IIS you are using.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI"/>
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
  <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI"/>
</httpModules>

<modules>
  <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</handlers>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am allowing uploads of pdf's, tiff's, word docs, excel, and some other formats; so I tried to modify your code a bit to make that work, but I just ended up with errors on the AsynchUpload. I switched back over tot he RadUpload control and attempted to stram to the db as the ultimate goal is, but I still get the same results...On button click the page refreshes and nothing uploads.

Comment: Do you have write access to the folder that you want to upload?

Comment: I updated the question to show the stream to the database so that I would not have to troubleshoot folder permissions, but yes, I have full access to the folder.

Comment: Here's my web.config entries:   + Modules:<add name="RadUploadModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" />  + Handlers: <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" /> + httphandlers: <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />   + httpModules: <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" />

Comment: I added my web.config setting. I run the page using your code. It upload the files (refer to the screenshot).

Comment: Darn it, it mist be something else going on on the page, or DotNetNuke interfering, are you running it in a DNN module or just as a stand-alone page?

Comment: *must* - I am going to create a new DNN module with just the upload and see if it works.

Comment: So I created a new module and used just the upload control. No Go. It must be DNN causing the problem, but where!!?? My code is obviously fine if it works for you. I tried to just change a label text on button click after the initial IF statement where it checks to see if the upload file count is > 0, but it does not work, it's like it's not seeing the upload control when I click the button....hmmm.....*/banging head on desk/*

Comment: I tested in a stand alone web project. Please make sure you have included the following. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/dnn-how-to-install-radupload-module--dnn-portal.html <RewriterRule>
    <LookFor>.*Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx</LookFor>
    <SendTo>~/Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx</SendTo>
</RewriterRule>

Comment: Holy cow!! Two things...I changed the name of the upload control from "RadUpload1" to "DocumantsRadUpload" and that got the control actually working!!! Not sure why. And to get the progress area indicator working, I had to disable "Partial Rendering" in the module control in DNN. What a pain!! Thank you very much for all your help, I would not have known that my code was even close to being right if you had not verified it for me!